# How to migrate Group module from 2.0 to 3.0?

Tags: group

I am working on implementing the Group module on Drupal 9.  The Release Notes describe moving from Group 2.0.x to 3.0.x as a 'Migration', which I take it is not just an upgrade that can be done using Composer.

Our overall project plan means we will need to do this migration on a site containing Group data, with associated content (Nodes) and members (Users).

Without considering the migration of custom modules, how can we perform this migration?

Comment: I downvoted this because you did not cite the documentation you referred to, or, how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: I did not cite documentation because I was asking if there was any.  I did not arrive at a conclusion, but asked a question.

Comment: You referred to release notes. Which ones?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/group/releases/3.0.0-beta1.  and also 2.0.0-beta1, 2.0.0-beta2, 2.0.0-beta3, 3.0.0-beta2. 3.0.0-beta3.

Comment: The thing to do is to put that information into the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it *is* a migration. A [revealing comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/3305008#comment-14660950) by the maintainer in its issue queue and the comments following it explain the details of migration to 2.0 and summarize the smaller changes of migration to 3.0.

Comment: Yet I I’ve read this information and still do not fully understand. You may need a better answer.

Comment: Indeed. I had already seen this, but don't understand what the 'migration involves, or how to perform it.

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer is referencing using the Drupal migrate module when using the word "migrate" as opposed to "upgrade".  So there is no "upgrade" path provided by the maintainer, meaning it isn't easy.  A "migration" in this case will look like creating another copy of your site removing all of the group and group content entities and uninstalling the group module.  From there you can install the group module fresh on version 3.x with the new flexible permissions module.  Setup all of your group types fresh and then "migrate" your content from the old copy of the site to the new copy of the site using the new architecture.

Comment: That's a terrible upgrade path, hopefully someone will come up with a better way before we have to do it.